# Cancel upload individually using jquery fileupload

Tags: jquery, file-upload

How can I abort the uploading of a particular file! I am attaching the jqXHR to the data attribute of the context and then I invoke the abourtUpload function that search for the data attribute and then try to abort it! But it is not working!

```
function abortUpload (e) {    
    e.preventDefault();
    var template = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.template-upload'),
    data = template.data('data') || {}; 
    console.log(data); // returns [Object object]
    data.jqXHR.abort(); // Cannot call method 'abort' of undefined 
}
// Method of fileupload
 add: function(e, data) {
      data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file)).attr('data-data', { jqXHR: data.submit() } );
      $('#fileupload').append(data.context);
      data.context.find('.cancel').click( abortUpload );
      return data.submit(); 
  }
```

Any idea guys?
Miguel.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store a jqXHR object as a HTML data attribute value, which is not possible.
You can only store objects in HTML data attributes that can be serialized as JSON.

What you could do is to use jQuery's .data() method to store the value, which allows to store arbitrary objects.

However, since all your code is in the same method, you don't need to do any of this, since you can simply use the local variables to access the jqXHR object and cancel the upload.
You also don't need to set data.context, since this is only used to set the context of jQuery.ajax requests.

So, the following snippet should help you get going:

```
var jqXHR = data.submit(),
    node = $(tmpl("template-upload", file)).appendTo('#fileupload');
node.find('.cancel').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jqXHR.abort();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much S, now it is clear, the only issue is whether should I attach the new node element created to data.context so I can use it  in the progress method to build the new progressbar of each new file added. I really appreciate your answer Man. Thank you!

Comment: Ey @Sebastian Tschan I think I should use data.context otherwise the progress method wont work propertly, if I use data.submit in add method the progress method works fine but the abort nop! Do you know why progress bar is not working propertly in the following code?

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9831004/data-context.png

Thank you for any idea.
M.

Comment: Finally I think I got it by creating a start trigger and submitting the data when is clicked! Thank you Sebastian!